# Windows network pass diff from desktop?

Tags: windows

I actually like having my desktop not having a password but i need it to be sharable so my VM can access it (however if i can make it share within 127.0.0.1 that be nice). Because its sharable i don't want people on the network to be able to access my desktop (its wifi).

Is it possible i can have a complex network password and have no password on my windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend setting a user password anyway and simply turn on autologin.

That way you'll be able to access your shares from any other host in your network provided you enter valid credentials but on system boot you won't have to enter a password.

There's a tool from microsoft you can use to set up [autologin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx).